# Dismiss WebView after OAuth2.0 FitBit authentication with OAuthSwift in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, fitbit

I am trying to pull FitBit user data using the OAuthSwift Library in an Objective C based app. I cannot get the webview to dismiss once the user has hit "Allow" and the callback url is displayed but neither the success or failure blocks of the authorization function are triggered so I also don't have access to any of the data. It just stalls at the callback URL and there is nothing the user can do to get out of the webview.

All of this is a reinterpretation of the [documentation](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift) from swift to objective c so there could be an issue with my translation but I dont understand why it wouldn't work and based on what I have read on their (and other people's) github the library is compatible with an Obj-C based app.

In my AppDelegate I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url 
sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:
(id)annotation
{
    if([url.host  isEqual: @"CALLBACKURL"])
    {
        [OAuthSwift handleWithUrl:url];
        [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"Dismiss View");
    }
    NSLog(@"THIS IS BEING CALLED");
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options
{
    if([url.host  isEqual: @"CALLBACKURL"])
    {
        [OAuthSwift handleWithUrl:url];
        [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        NSLog(@"Dismiss View");
    }
    NSLog(@"THIS IS BEING CALLED");
    return YES;
}
```

And Within the View Controller that presents the authentication process I have:

```
- (IBAction)synchFitBit:(id)sender
{
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"consumerKey": @"MYKEY",
                             @"consumerSecret": @"MYSECRET",
                             @"authorizeUrl": @"https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize",
                             @"accessTokenUrl": @"https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token",
                             @"responseType" : @"code"
                             };


    OAuth2Swift *oauth = [[OAuth2Swift alloc] initWithParameters:parameters];
    oauth.client.paramsLocation = ParamsLocationRequestURIQuery;

    SafariURLHandler *safariURLHandler = [[SafariURLHandler alloc] initWithViewController:self oauthSwift:oauth];
    safariURLHandler.delegate = self;
    oauth.authorizeURLHandler = safariURLHandler;


    [oauth objc_authorizeWithCallbackURL:@"CALLBACKURL" scope:@"activity" state:@"" parameters:parameters headers:parameters
                              success:^(OAuthSwiftCredential *credential, OAuthSwiftResponse *response, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *parameters) {
                                  NSString *userId = parameters[@"userid"];

                                  NSLog(@"SUCSESS: %@",userId);
                              }
                              failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"FAILURE");
                              }];

}
```

None of the NSLogs in those functions appear in the console which is mostly why I am lost. Even if I could give the user a way to dismiss the webview themselve while still triggering the success block of objc_authorizeWithCallbackURL that would be fine. I appreciate any advice and let me know if I should provide more code/info. Thanks!

Edit: Changed webview to SFViewController based on comment. Now the user sees a "Done" button which will trigger the safariViewControllerDidFinish function correctly but I still don't see any data or any sort of success or failure related to the OAuth2.0 Process.

Comment: As I understand things, You should NOT use webview with OAuth 2.0 due to vulnerabilities. WebView is single-process, so any security vulnerability in the renderer engine practically grants any malicious code the same rights as your application has. You should use SFSafariViewController.

Comment: @jwilleke Thanks I changed to an SFSafariViewController but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone else will encounter this error but I might as well post what fixed it for me.

The key is to set a custom URL scheme within "URL Types" under YourProjectTarget>Info and then use the scheme in the callback URL so that app delegate can pick it up. So if you set your scheme to "myscheme" then your callback url should look like myscheme://www.mycallbackurl.com/

Hope this helps someone!